# Why doesn't my pd.dataframe see the columns in my csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I seem to be running into errors when I try to load a CSV file into a dataframe and then do data analysis on it.

I am running into trouble creating a simple plot using the columns as the data points.

`df.{column name}` isn't working.

The code:

```py
import pandas as pd

#column_names = ['area', 'bedrooms', 'age', 'price', 'Unnamed']
df = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv")
print(df)
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')] # rRemove NAN column
print(df)

print(df.bedrooms.median())
```

The error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'bedrooms'
```

The CSV file:

```
area, bedrooms, age, price,
2600, 3,        20,  550000,
3000, 4,        15,  565000,
3200, 0,        18,  610000,
3600, 3,        30,  595000,
4000, 5,        8,   760000,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You columns have whitespace around them:

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['area', ' bedrooms', ' age', ' price'], dtype='object')
                ^            ^       ^
```

You can remove it using `.str.strip()` (just like you'd do with a normal Series):

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df.bedrooms.median())
3.0
```

---

You can also correct the CSV file, by removing all whitespace before/after the commas in the header of the CSV:

```
area,bedrooms,age,price,
2600, 3,        20,  550000,
3000, 4,        15,  565000,
3200, 0,        18,  610000,
3600, 3,        30,  595000,
4000, 5,        8,   760000,
```